# Inserir imagem de fundo em JPanel

Tags: java, interface, jpanel

Já verifiquei e o caminho está correto, porém quando executo não aparece nada na tela:

```
public class MapaInterface extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private Image fundo;
public static Agente daenerys;
private Timer timer;

public MapaInterface() {
    String caminho = "/res/mapaGot.png";
    URL url = getClass().getResource(caminho);
    ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon(caminho);
    fundo = referencia.getImage();
    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();
}

public void Paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D graficos = (Graphics2D) g;
    //null = fundo estático
    graficos.drawImage(fundo, 0, 0, null);
    //atualiza a imagem
    graficos.drawImage(daenerys.getImagem(), daenerys.getPosicao().getX(), daenerys.getPosicao().getY(), this);
    g.dispose();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
}

public static Agente getDaenerys() {
    return daenerys;
}

public static void setDaenerys(Agente daenerys) {
    MapaInterface.daenerys = daenerys;
}
```

Quando chamo a classe:

```
public class ContainerDeJanelas extends JFrame{

    public ContainerDeJanelas(){
        add(new MapaInterface());
        setTitle("Heurística Game of Thrones");
        //tamanho da tela
        setSize(750,750);
        //usuario nao pode redimensionar a tela
        setResizable(false);
        //evento ao clicar em fechar
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //onde a janela vai aparecer (null = centro)
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

main:

```
   ContainerDeJanelas containerDeJanelas = new ContainerDeJanelas();
```

Comment: Experimenta usar uma imagem (url) da internet e/ou usar um caminho absoluto. Eu lembro que já passei por algo similar. Por algum motivo o programa não conseguia acessar o arquivo; como se ele não existisse. Resolvi usando um caminho absoluto.

Comment: O problema é que a imagem tem que ser essa, é uma imagem que eu criei. O que seria um caminho absoluto? já testei de todo jeito

Comment: Caminho absoluto é do tipo "C:\minha pasta\programa\figuras\icone.png". A ideia de usar um caminho absoluto (ou uma url) é só pra ver se a imagem aparecerá conforme desejado.

Para determinar se o problema está no código ou no caminho (como eu citei, às vezes o arquivo pode estar invisível para o programa; o que parece que aconteceu comigo - e não sei resolver).

Comment: Aaah deu certo! Obrigada :)

Comment: Fechei como duplicata pois a forma de se resolver é semelhante ao que foi respondida na outra pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução que consiste em achar o caminho absoluto da imagem a partir do caminho do qual o programa está sendo executado; e adicionar a ele o caminho relativo da imagem.

Adaptando ao seu programa, mude o construtor da classe MapaInterface para:

```
public MapaInterface() {
    String caminhoRelativo = "/res/mapaGot.png";

    String caminhoExecucao = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

    String caminhoAbsoluto = caminhoExecucao + caminhoRelativo ;

    ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon(caminhoAbsoluto );
    fundo = referencia.getImage();    
    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();
}
```